# ¿Por qué tengo este error al importar una clase en typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy importando una clase a index.ts y obtengo este error:

```
[run] import { Sorter } from './Sorter';
[run] ^^^^^^
[run]
[run] SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

el archivo indes.ts es:

```
import { Sorter } from './Sorter';
import { NumbersCollection } from './NumbersCollections';

const numbersCollection = new NumbersCollection([10, 3, -5, 0]);
const sorter = new Sorter(numbersCollection);
sorter.sort();
console.log(numbersCollection);
```

y la clase se está exportando desde aquí Sorter.ts:

```
interface Sortable {
  length: number;
  compare(leftIndex: number, rightIndex: number): boolean;
  swap(leftIndex: number, rightIndex: number): void;
}

export class Sorter {
  constructor(public collection: Sortable) {}

  sort(): void {
    const { length } = this.collection; // this.collection.length

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (this.collection.compare(j, j + 1)) {
          this.collection.swap(j, j + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Como tienes configurados los módulos en tu `tsconfig`..??

Comment: Lo configuré así  "module": "es6"